# MITMProxy how to remove flows so they do not show up in MITMWeb

Tags: python, ads, mitmproxy

I'd like to use MITMProxy Python scripting to remove flows that i find useless from the web interface.

Lets say i kill a flow

```
def request(flow):
        if("ads" in flow.request.url):
                flow.kill()
```

But also i would like killed connections to not show up in my MITMWeb interface.

An example can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1YWL.jpg

I am unable to find a way programatically to delete the requests from the list.

I would only like to see the connections that make it through.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide some more explanation?

Comment: MITMWeb shows all connections, including the killed ones. That fills the web interface with much clutter. https://imgur.com/a/la0RDmh

Answer (score 1):

**Using filter**

It's possible to filter out these requests and they won't appear in interface: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-filters/

In this case, by applying filter: `! googleadservices`

**Using ignore_hosts option**

Or, using option `ignore_hosts` to ignore these requests completely. These requests will bypass mitmproxy:
https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/

In this case, by applying option when starting web interface: `mitmweb --set ignore_hosts='www.googleadservices.com'`

It's also possible to edit ignore hosts in web interface: Options tab -> Edit options -> find ignore hosts and modify it.

Comment: I understand that i can filter requests. That is not the goal. I can only hide googleadservices that way. I want to filter requests based on their STATE. AKA a killed state. Ignoring hosts is also not an options seen as i want those connections to be killed. I do not wish to ignore them.

Comment: You could mark the killed requests in your script:
...
if("ads" in flow.request.url):
    **flow.marked = True**
    flow.kill()
...
Then use filter to filter out these marked requests: **!~marked**
Hope that can do the trick you want.

Comment: Ill try that and get back to you

Comment: @benzoid did you eventually solve this?

Answer (score 1):

the current implementation to remove flow can be found on [view module](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/31f089cb8dae49a8cdb5d77c03088b62fcd1f910/mitmproxy/addons/view.py#L417) but it may not directly usable in add-ons

with that you can create your own remove method

```py
class CustomAddOn:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            if hasattr(ctx, "master"):
                self.view = ctx.master.addons.get("view")
        except Exception as err:
            self.view = None

    def remove(self, flows: typing.Sequence[mitmproxy.flow.Flow], kill=True, log=True) -> None:
        """
            Removes the flow from the underlying store and the view.
        """
        for f in flows:
            if f.id in self.view._store:
                if f.killable and kill:
                    f.kill()
                if f in self.view._view:
                    # We manually pass the index here because multiple flows may have the same
                    # sorting key, and we cannot reconstruct the index from that.
                    idx = self.view._view.index(f)
                    self.view._view.remove(f)
                    self.view.sig_view_remove.send(self, flow=f, index=idx)
                del self.view._store[f.id]
                self.view.sig_store_remove.send(self, flow=f)
        if len(flows) > 1 and log:
            ctx.log.alert("Removed %s flows" % len(flows))
```

note for edits from the original code

- option to not kill the flow. sometime you may want to remove but not kill the flow
- option to not log. if you run from concurrent request or response, you want to avoid ctx.log and use your own logger
- when you initialize your add-on, you may not have ctx.master